# Using unlist while preserving column integrity

Tags: r

I have a list of data (see `dput`) that represents 16 distinct lists/columns each with 6 rows.  I would like to store the numeric values from this list in the format of 6 rows x 16 columns.

However when I used the function unlist:

```
matrix(unlist(output), ncol = length(methodlist), byrow = TRUE)
```

It actually scrambles the order of the data, and column integrity is destroyed.  Is there a workaround to this solution?

```
dput(output)
list(list(17527.828266847, 17598.3098269261, 16345.0619305947, 
    20773.5367611918, 16354.9859654573, 16090.7093252554), list(
    18003.8817822465, 18021.2396365718, 16579.4034877518, 22171.0939388498, 
    16758.9649897592, 16502.4979715065), list(c(mu = 18004.4236490711), 
    c(mu = 18047.0830637736), c(mu = 16561.4563719839), c(mu = 22374.7016985937), 
    c(mu = 16714.8614541359), c(mu = 16456.6171625894)), list(
    c(`14` = 17947.9092138984), c(`13` = 18190.7855395632), c(`12` = 16758.6736148157), 
    c(`11` = 22225.3831605073), c(`10` = 16963.0732943225), c(`9` = 17088.3342570797)), 
    list(c(`14` = 17344.37847326), c(`13` = 18760.2146284561), 
        c(`12` = 17253.6812982067), c(`11` = 21894.862967024), 
        c(`10` = 16611.5287006207), c(`9` = 16598.5208423059)), 
    list(17833.0439619645, 18487.2549805515, 16775.2810432234, 
        22327.7009340556, 17209.1272199995, 17292.4505336839), 
    list(c(`14` = 17409.7205149158), c(`13` = 17124.4355791922), 
        c(`12` = 16996.9828871729), c(`11` = 21442.3700316185), 
        c(`10` = 16013.290619632), c(`9` = 16361.6862148874)), 
    list(structure(17527.828266847, .Dim = c(1L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        "14", NULL)), structure(17598.3098269261, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("13", NULL)), structure(16345.0619305947, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("12", NULL)), structure(20773.5367611918, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("11", NULL)), structure(16354.9859654573, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("10", NULL)), structure(16090.7093252554, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list("9", NULL))), list(c(`14` = 18047.5102898349), 
        c(`13` = 18339.2060049905), c(`12` = 17230.8867248462), 
        c(`11` = 21424.1204199137), c(`10` = 17486.6600935458), 
        c(`9` = 17591.5679374626)), list(c(`14` = 18067.7115720011), 
        c(`13` = 18367.3788546756), c(`12` = 17277.7911085028), 
        c(`11` = 21587.3486900132), c(`10` = 17480.9375935945), 
        c(`9` = 17619.4896096197)), list(18364.5115406765, 18468.3304514576, 
        16995.6774602581, 22385.8626143146, 17243.2333207718, 
        17310.8209168516), list(structure(17705.6373865059, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y")), structure(18523.2594748306, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y")), structure(16183.4986872021, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y")), structure(24813.0989550588, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y")), structure(16831.8703548531, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y")), structure(17431.957411153, .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y"))), list(18190.212890625, 
        18840.5078125, 16158.65625, 21973.47265625, 17228.591796875, 
        17133.416015625), list(17463.3280982261, 18020.7996214448, 
        16936.0463289012, 22214.5687454093, 16933.1962847704, 
        17623.8398188916), list(c(`14` = 17701.3706417831), c(`13` = 17945.0965772174), 
        c(`12` = 16980.1488257834), c(`11` = 22021.4257870094), 
        c(`10` = 16600.4993745862), c(`9` = 15668.2143659731)), 
    list(c(`14` = 17409.7205149158), c(`13` = 17382.2389904494), 
        c(`12` = 16269.1823921211), c(`11` = 22369.2959527086), 
        c(`10` = 16429.0492832497), c(`9` = 15668.2143659731)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unlist` concatenates all values into a sequence. If you want to fill your matrix by row, you need to transpose it:

```
t(matrix(unlist(output), ncol = 6, byrow = T))
```

Or, you can simply fill your matrix by column:

```
matrix(unlist(output), ncol = 16)
```